# Does someone know what is the best way to create the following bibliographiestyle?

Tags: bibliographies, cross-referencing, bold, custom-bib

I write my thesis and I have to use the following style for my References. 
[image: Bibliographie style]
I could not find any existing style which looks similar and I could not make this style with makebst. 
The Problem is that i have to write (author year et al.) in bold letters and after this i have to write all the authors again but in normal font. 
Maybe it will work with makebst, but i failed. 
I also tried different styles in natbib but none of them looks similar to the one i need.
Would be really thankfull if somone could help me. 
Dirk

Edit: Maybe it is important: I have a lot of references so i imported them from citavi. And i also managed to create a file with makebst with bold authors and year, but not with the second mentioning of all authors. 
Edit2: Here is my file which i created with makebst to get this:

[image: pic2]

is it possible to change sth. in the file to get my requiered bibliographystyle->all the authors after the bold (author year)?

```
%%


ENTRY
  { address
    author
    booktitle
    chapter
    doi
    edition
    editor
    eid
    howpublished
    institution
    isbn
    issn
    journal
    key
    month
    note
    number
    organization
    pages
    publisher
    school
    series
    title
    type
    url
    volume
    year
  }
  {}
  { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
INTEGERS { output.state before.all mid.sentence after.sentence after.block }
FUNCTION {init.state.consts}
{ #0 'before.all :=
  #1 'mid.sentence :=
  #2 'after.sentence :=
  #3 'after.block :=
}
STRINGS { s t}
FUNCTION {output.nonnull}
{ 's :=
  output.state mid.sentence =
    { ", " * write$ }
    { output.state after.block =
        { add.period$ write$
          newline$
          "\newblock " write$
        }
        { output.state before.all =
            'write$
            { add.period$ " " * write$ }
          if$
        }
      if$
      mid.sentence 'output.state :=
    }
  if$
  s
}
FUNCTION {output}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {output.check}
{ 't :=
  duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "empty " t * " in " * cite$ * warning$ }
    'output.nonnull
  if$
}
FUNCTION {fin.entry}
{ add.period$
  write$
  newline$
}

FUNCTION {new.block}
{ output.state before.all =
    'skip$
    { after.block 'output.state := }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.sentence}
{ output.state after.block =
    'skip$
    { output.state before.all =
        'skip$
        { after.sentence 'output.state := }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {add.blank}
{  " " * before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {date.block}
{
  new.block
}

FUNCTION {not}
{   { #0 }
    { #1 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {and}
{   'skip$
    { pop$ #0 }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {or}
{   { pop$ #1 }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {new.block.checkb}
{ empty$
  swap$ empty$
  and
    'skip$
    'new.block
  if$
}
FUNCTION {field.or.null}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    'skip$
  if$
}
FUNCTION {emphasize}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\emph{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bolden}
{ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "" }
    { "\textbf{" swap$ * "}" * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {bib.name.font}
{ bolden }
FUNCTION {bib.fname.font}
{ bib.name.font }
FUNCTION {tie.or.space.prefix}
{ duplicate$ text.length$ #3  }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}{, f.}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      type$ "presentation" =
        { check.speaker }
        'skip$
      if$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #1 + =
          numnames #1
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { "; " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              ";" *
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                  bib.name.font
                }
                { " " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  t "others" =
    'skip$
    { bib.name.font }
  if$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.names.ed}
{
  'bibinfo :=
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$ {
  's :=
  "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{f.~}{vv~}{ll}{, jj}"
      format.name$
      bibinfo bibinfo.check
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          namesleft #1 >
            { "; " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              ";" *
              t "others" =
                {

                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                { " " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
  } if$
}
FUNCTION {format.key}
{ empty$
    { key field.or.null }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.authors}
{ author "author" format.names
}
FUNCTION {get.bbl.editor}
{ editor num.names$ #1 > 'bbl.editors 'bbl.editor if$ }

FUNCTION {format.editors}
{ editor "editor" format.names duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      "," *
      " " *
      get.bbl.editor
      *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.isbn}
{ isbn "isbn" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      new.block
      "ISBN " swap$ *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.issn}
{ issn "issn" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      new.block
      "ISSN " swap$ *
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.doi}
{ doi empty$
    { "" }
    {
      new.block
      "\doi{" doi * "}" *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.note}
{
 note empty$
    { "" }
    { note #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "{" =
        'skip$
        { output.state mid.sentence =
          { "l" }
          { "u" }
        if$
        change.case$
        }
      if$
      note #2 global.max$ substring$ * "note" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.title}
{ title
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { "t" change.case$ }
  if$
  "title" bibinfo.check
}
FUNCTION {format.full.names}
{'s :=
 "" 't :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
      't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #1 + =
          numnames #1
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            {
              s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                { 't := }
                { pop$ }
              if$
              t "others" =
                {
                  " " * bbl.etal *
                }
                {
                  bbl.and
                  space.word * t *
                }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {author.editor.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { editor empty$
        { key empty$
            { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
            'key
          if$
        }
        { editor format.full.names }
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {author.key.full}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { author format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {editor.key.full}
{ editor empty$
    { key empty$
         { cite$ #1 #3 substring$ }
          'key
      if$
    }
    { editor format.full.names }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {make.full.names}
{ type$ "book" =
  type$ "inbook" =
  or
    'author.editor.key.full
    { type$ "proceedings" =
        'editor.key.full
        'author.key.full
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {output.bibitem}
{ newline$
  "\bibitem[{" write$
  label write$
  ")" make.full.names duplicate$ short.list =
     { pop$ }
     { * }
   if$
  "}]{" * write$
  cite$ write$
  "}" write$
  newline$
  ""
  before.all 'output.state :=
}

FUNCTION {n.dashify}
{
  't :=
  ""
    { t empty$ not }
    { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" =
        { t #1 #2 substring$ "--" = not
            { "--" *
              t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
            }
            {   { t #1 #1 substring$ "-" = }
                { "-" *
                  t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
                }
              while$
            }
          if$
        }
        { t #1 #1 substring$ *
          t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't :=
        }
      if$
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {word.in}
{ bbl.in capitalize
  " " * }

FUNCTION {format.date}
{ year "year" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$
    {
    }
    'skip$
  if$
  extra.label *
}
FUNCTION {format.btitle}
{ title "title" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      emphasize
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {either.or.check}
{ empty$
    'pop$
    { "can't use both " swap$ * " fields in " * cite$ * warning$ }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.bvolume}
{ volume empty$
    { "" }
    { bbl.volume volume tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check * *
      series "series" bibinfo.check
      duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        { swap$ bbl.of space.word * swap$
          emphasize * }
      if$
      "volume and number" number either.or.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.number.series}
{ volume empty$
    { number empty$
        { series field.or.null }
        { series empty$
            { number "number" bibinfo.check }
            { output.state mid.sentence =
                { bbl.number }
                { bbl.number capitalize }
              if$
              number tie.or.space.prefix "number" bibinfo.check * *
              bbl.in space.word *
              series "series" bibinfo.check *
            }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
    { "" }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.edition}
{ edition duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      output.state mid.sentence =
        { "l" }
        { "t" }
      if$ change.case$
      "edition" bibinfo.check
      " " * bbl.edition *
    }
  if$
}
INTEGERS { multiresult }
FUNCTION {multi.page.check}
{ 't :=
  #0 'multiresult :=
    { multiresult not
      t empty$ not
      and
    }
    { t #1 #1 substring$
      duplicate$ "-" =
      swap$ duplicate$ "," =
      swap$ "+" =
      or or
        { #1 'multiresult := }
        { t #2 global.max$ substring$ 't := }
      if$
    }
  while$
  multiresult
}
FUNCTION {format.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    { duplicate$ multi.page.check
        {
          bbl.pages swap$
          n.dashify
        }
        {
          bbl.page swap$
        }
      if$
      tie.or.space.prefix
      "pages" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.pages}
{ pages duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { pop$ pop$ format.pages }
        {
          ":" *
          swap$
          n.dashify
          "pages" bibinfo.check
          *
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.journal.eid}
{ eid "eid" bibinfo.check
  duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
    { swap$ duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
      {
          ":" *
      }
      if$
      swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.vol.num.pages}
{ volume field.or.null
  duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      bbl.volume swap$ tie.or.space.prefix
      "volume" bibinfo.check
      * *
    }
  if$
  number "number" bibinfo.check duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      swap$ duplicate$ empty$
        { "there's a number but no volume in " cite$ * warning$ }
        'skip$
      if$
      swap$
      "(" swap$ * ")" *
    }
  if$ *
  eid empty$
    { format.journal.pages }
    { format.journal.eid }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.chapter.pages}
{ chapter empty$
    'format.pages
    { type empty$
        { bbl.chapter }
        { type "l" change.case$
          "type" bibinfo.check
        }
      if$
      chapter tie.or.space.prefix
      "chapter" bibinfo.check
      * *
      pages empty$
        'skip$
        { ", " * format.pages * }
      if$
    }
  if$
}

FUNCTION {format.booktitle}
{
  booktitle "booktitle" bibinfo.check
  emphasize
}
FUNCTION {format.in.ed.booktitle}
{ format.booktitle duplicate$ empty$ 'skip$
    {
      editor "editor" format.names.ed duplicate$ empty$ 'pop$
        {
          "," *
          " " *
          get.bbl.editor
          ", " *
          * swap$
          * }
      if$
      word.in swap$ *
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.thesis.type}
{ type duplicate$ empty$
    'pop$
    { swap$ pop$
      "t" change.case$ "type" bibinfo.check
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.tr.number}
{ number "number" bibinfo.check
  type duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ bbl.techrep }
    'skip$
  if$
  "type" bibinfo.check
  swap$ duplicate$ empty$
    { pop$ "t" change.case$ }
    { tie.or.space.prefix * * }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.article.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.book.crossref}
{ volume duplicate$ empty$
    { "empty volume in " cite$ * "'s crossref of " * crossref * warning$
      pop$ word.in
    }
    { bbl.volume
      capitalize
      swap$ tie.or.space.prefix "volume" bibinfo.check * * bbl.of space.word *
    }
  if$
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.incoll.inproc.crossref}
{
  word.in
  " \cite{" * crossref * "}" *
}
FUNCTION {format.org.or.pub}
{ 't :=
  ""
  address empty$ t empty$ and
    'skip$
    {
      t empty$
        { address "address" bibinfo.check *
        }
        { t *
          address empty$
            'skip$
            { ", " * address "address" bibinfo.check * }
          if$
        }
      if$
    }
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.publisher.address}
{ publisher "publisher" bibinfo.warn format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {format.organization.address}
{ organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
}

FUNCTION {article}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    {
      journal
      "journal" bibinfo.check
      emphasize
      "journal" output.check
      format.date "year" output.check
      date.block
      format.vol.num.pages output
    }
    { format.article.crossref output.nonnull
      format.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {booklet}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn output
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {inbook}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    {
      format.bvolume output
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      format.chapter.pages "chapter and pages" output.check
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.edition output
  crossref missing$
    { format.isbn output }
    'skip$
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {incollection}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      format.chapter.pages output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
      format.edition output
      format.isbn output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
      format.chapter.pages output
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {inproceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  new.block
  crossref missing$
    { format.in.ed.booktitle "booktitle" output.check
      format.bvolume output
      format.number.series output
      new.sentence
      publisher empty$
        { format.organization.address output }
        { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
          format.publisher.address output
        }
      if$
      format.isbn output
      format.issn output
    }
    { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  add.blank
  format.pages "pages" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {conference} { inproceedings }
FUNCTION {manual}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  organization address new.block.checkb
  organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.edition output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {mastersthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  new.block
  bbl.mthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {misc}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title output
  new.block
  howpublished "howpublished" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
FUNCTION {phdthesis}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle
  "title" output.check
  new.block
  bbl.phdthesis format.thesis.type output.nonnull
  school "school" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {presentation}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors output
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title output
  new.block
  format.organization.address "organization and address" output.check
  month "month" output.check
  year "year" output.check
  new.block
  format.note output
  new.sentence
  type missing$ 'skip$
  {"(" type capitalize * ")" * output}
    if$
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {proceedings}
{ output.bibitem
  format.editors output
  editor format.key output
  new.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  format.bvolume output
  format.number.series output
  new.sentence
  publisher empty$
    { format.organization.address output }
    { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
      format.publisher.address output
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.isbn output
  format.issn output
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {techreport}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title
  "title" output.check
  new.block
  format.tr.number output.nonnull
  institution "institution" bibinfo.warn output
  address "address" bibinfo.check output
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {unpublished}
{ output.bibitem
  format.authors "author" output.check
  author format.key output
  new.block
  format.title "title" output.check
  format.date "year" output.check
  format.doi output
  new.block
  format.note "note" output.check
  fin.entry
  write.url
}

FUNCTION {default.type} { misc }
READ
FUNCTION {sortify}
{ purify$
  "l" change.case$
}
INTEGERS { len }
FUNCTION {chop.word}
{ 's :=
  'len :=
  s #1 len substring$ =
    { s len #1 + global.max$ substring$ }
    's
  if$
}
FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
{ 's :=
  "" 't :=
  s #1 "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
  s num.names$ duplicate$
  #2 >
    { pop$
      " " * bbl.etal *
    }
    { #2  }
    { s nameptr
      "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  f{ }}{  jj{ }}"
      format.name$ 't :=
      nameptr #1 >
        {
          nameptr #1
          #1 + =
          numnames #1
          > and
            { "others" 't :=
              #1 'namesleft := }
            'skip$
          if$
          "   "  *
          namesleft #1 = t "others" = and
            { "zzzzz" 't := }
            'skip$
          if$
          t sortify *
        }
        { t sortify * }
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}

FUNCTION {sort.format.title}
{ 't :=
  "A " #2
    "An " #3
      "The " #4 t chop.word
    chop.word
  chop.word
  sortify
  #1 global.max$ substring$
}
FUNCTION {author.sort}
{ author empty$
    { key empty$
        { "to sort, need author or key in " cite$ * warning$
          ""
        }
        { key sortify }
      if$
    }
    { author sort.format.names }
  if$
}
```

Comment: Can you use [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)?

Comment: Yes i think so. Is it possible with biblatex.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Comment: Is there any news here?